# How to propertly configure my pre-commit and pre-push hooks?

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I have a simple python project with a single file currently. It exists within the static/cgi-bin folder of my project. Currently, in the base of my directory, I have a .pre-commit-config.yaml file, and I have not touched the files in the .git/hooks folder. I would like to create pre-commit and pre-push hooks, but I can not seem to get it working.

When I try to commit, the following happens:

```
isort................................................(no files to check)Skipped
flake8...............................................(no files to check)Skipped
black................................................(no files to check)Skipped
```

When I try to push, I get the following error:

```
pytest...................................................................Failed
hookid: pytest

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.15, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
rootdir: /Users/.../deployment, inifile:
collected 0 items
========================= no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================
error: failed to push some refs to '...git'
```

Note that deployment is the folder I am working in.

My code in the yaml file is:

```
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    - id: isort
      name: isort
      entry: isort
      language: system
      types: [python]
      stages: [commit]
    - id: flake8
      name: flake8
      language: system
      entry: flake8
      types: [python]
      stages: [commit]
    - id: black
      language_version: python3.6
      name: black
      language: system
      entry: black
      types: [python]
      stages: [commit]
    - id: pytest
      name: pytest
      language: system
      entry: pytest
      pass_filenames: false
      always_run: true
      stages: [push]
```

Comment: I think you are using https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit-hooks here, which is just one of many ways to define a git hook. If so could you clarify your question?

Comment: Please, get some information about local git hooks at http://githooks.com

Answer (score 24):

`pre-commit` will pass a list of [staged files which match `types` / `files`](https://pre-commit.com/#arguments-pattern-in-hooks) to the `entry` listed.

Your commit shows "no files to check" because there were no python files in your commit.  You probably want to run `pre-commit run --all-files` when first introducing new hooks

As for your `pytest` hook, pytest exits nonzero when it does not run any tests and so that is failing.